# No .sln or .vcporj files get generated from runhooks when compiling Chromium

Tags: chromium, vcproj, gyp

So I'm attempting my first Chrome build just for fun and I've gotten all the files I want through gclient config and sync. However, there are no project files that VS can open, just a bunch of .gyp files that are useless to me.

The command 'gclient runhooks --force' is supposed to generate the sln files for me, but when I run it I get nothing. Not even an error.

What's up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this info still seems to be missing from the Chromium documentation at the moment. The way to generate your Visual Studio Solution files is:

```
export GYP_GENERATORS=msvs-ninja
gclient runhooks --force
```

You won't need the `--force` if it's your first time calling `gclient runhooks`. The generator should be good for your ninja build and it should generate your .sln files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, really annoying problem... I did all kinds of stuff to make it work, and this is how I made it work in the end, believe it or not:

1. Restart PC
2. In terminal `cd` to the dir containing .gclient file
3. *checkout Important note below if you never used GYP before*
4. `gclient runhooks --force`
5. profit

**Important:** You must also set environment variable named `GYP_GENERATORS` to a value listing build project types. For example, to generate NINJA build files and Microsoft Visual Studio (your case) do this if in linux terminal `export GYP_GENERATORS=ninja,msvs` or if Windows cmd `setx GYP_GENERATORS ninja,msvs /M` before **step 4**. This way you control what project types will  be generated on runhooks.